# Undigested Asset links in Rails 4.1 css.sass file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I recently upgrade from rails 3.2 to rails 4.1.
In my `user.css.sass` file I have

```
#profile
  background: image-url('icon_user.png')
```

Now when I run `rake assets:precompile` I expect to find a digested link in the user.css file, but I have

```
#profile{background:url(/assets/icon_user.png)};
```

This used work as rails produced undigested asset files along the ones with digests.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I don't understand, what is wrong with the compiled results?

Comment: It links to the undigested asset file. In Rails 3 this worked, because the assets were generated both in a digested and in an undigested way, but in Rails 4 only digested assets are generated. And so the urls in css should have link to digested asset files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were changes in Rails 4 regarding generation of assets. In Rails 3 both "digested" and "plain" assets were generated. In Rails 4 you should configure your system to get digested assets in development environment.

According to the [The Asset Pipeline page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) in Rails guides:

> Fingerprinting is enabled by default for production and disabled for all other environments. You can enable or disable it in your configuration through the `config.assets.digest` option.

If you compile assets in development you will get "plain" names. Enable them in your `development.rb` file changing setting `config.assets.digest = true`.

Comment: For development as such, I don't precompile assets. But the assets for production I precompile on the development machine in development mode (was assets mode in Rails 3.2), zip and scp to the server.

My generated css still links to the undigested assets

Comment: In the end your solution helped. The rest was just cleaning away old left over assets/emptying cache issues